# Making an acronym from user input string

Tags: java, string

I need my program to output an acronym, but I'm having trouble finding a way to omit other capital letters in the string that aren't the first letters. For example, if the input is "Awesome COOL Crazy" I get an output of "ACOOLC" instead of the desired "ACC".

I'm extremely new to this (you can probably tell by this question and by the code) so any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static String createAcronym(String userPhrase) {
      String newUserPhrase = userPhrase.replaceAll("\\s","");
      char acronymChar;
      String acronym = "";
      int i;
      
      for (i = 0; i < newUserPhrase.length(); ++i) {
         if ( (Character.isUpperCase(newUserPhrase.charAt(i))) ) {
            acronymChar = newUserPhrase.charAt(i);
            acronym += acronymChar + ".";
         }
      }
      return acronym;
   }
      
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String userPhrase = scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println(createAcronym(userPhrase));
   }
   }
```

I tried implementing an if statement that reads the next char in the user string, and then removing that char from the final acronym.

Comment: Rather then doing `String newUserPhrase = userPhrase.replaceAll("\\s","");`, use `String#split` to split the text on the spaces.  Then for each element, check the first character, if it's a capital letter, append it to your `acronym`

Comment: One liner: Single word string: (first three characters) OR Multi word string: (first letter from each word) - Java8+ required: Make sure `inputString` is not null or Empty: `String acronym = (!inputString.contains(" ") ? inputString.toUpperCase().substring(0, 3) : java.util.Arrays.stream(inputString.split("\\s+")).map(t -> t.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining("")));`

Answer (score 3):

Logic -

1. Break the string into Array using split.
2. Get the first character of every array element

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy";
        String acronym = "";
        String sArray[] = s.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<sArray.length; i++) {
            acronym += sArray[i].charAt(0);
        }
        System.out.println(acronym);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do never concatenate `String` in loop!

Answer (score 1):

So, rather then removing all the spaces, which removes your ability to determine the word boundaries, simply split the `String` on spaces.

This will give you an array of seperate `String`s, each representing a word in the original text.

Then, check if the first character of each word is upper case or not and append it your `acronym` if it is.

For example...

```
public static String createAcronym(String userPhrase) {
    String[] words = userPhrase.split("\\s");
    String acronym = "";
    for (String word : words) {
        if (!word.isBlank() && Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0))) {
            acronym += Character.toString(word.charAt(0));
        }
    }
    return acronym;
}
```

So an input of `"Awesome COOL Crazy"` will output `ACC`

I would also normally make use of `StringBuilder` rather then `String` concatenation, but I think you have enough to deal with right now

Answer (score 1):

Use a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, and the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes.

```
(?i)(?<=^|\s)[a-z]
```

```java
String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=^|\\s)[a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) b.append(m.group().toUpperCase());
```

Alternately, use the *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method.

```
(?i)(?<=[a-z]).*?(?:\s+|$)
```

```java
String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy".trim().toUpperCase();
s = s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=[a-z]).*?(?:\\s+|$)", "");
```

Another solution would be to utilize the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy".trim().toUpperCase();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
char c;
for (String v : s.split(" +"))
    if (Character.isLetter(c = v.charAt(0))) b.append(c);
```

Or, utilize the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class.

```java
String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy".toUpperCase();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
char c;
while (sc.hasNext())
    if (Character.isLetter(c = sc.next().charAt(0))) b.append(c);
```

Or finally, utilize the *[StringCharacterIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html)* class.

```java
String s = "Awesome COOL Crazy".trim().toUpperCase();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
StringCharacterIterator i = new StringCharacterIterator(s);
b.append(i.current());
do if (i.current() == ' ')
    do if (i.next() != ' ')
        if (Character.isLetter(i.current())) {
            b.append(i.current());
            break;
        }
    while (i.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE);
while (i.next() != CharacterIterator.DONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String getAcronyms(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
                 .map(word -> String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)))
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

```java
public static String getAcronyms(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (i == 0 || str.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));

    return buf.toString();
}
```